# What MySQL type for long descriptions with punctuation?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store long descriptions with symbols such as $ and punctuation. The original type I used cut the text off early. The second type I used outputs the following...

> *"Â Â Tickets are $13.00 for adults, $11.00 for seniors,Â $5.00 for children ages 5-11 and free for children under 5.Â Â There is also a family rateÂ of $35.00 available for 2Â adults and up to 4 children.Â  All prices include taxes.Â Â Reservations are recommended.Â  Please callÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â 519-661-5000Â Â Â Â Â Â Â orÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â 1-800-265-2602Â Â Â Â Â Â Â for reservations."*

Is there a type I can use to avoid this? Or will I have to convert punctuation before I put it into the database?

The types I've tried are Varchar & Mediumtext.

*EDIT: Size problem has been solved but still getting the 'Â Â ' characters.*

Comment: what types did you try already?

Comment: I suspect, your problem is related to character encoding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) type. It can hold up to 65KB.

If you use the proper encoding (like UTF-8), there is no problem in storing *puncturation* characters.

You can also use `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` if you need to store up to 16MB or 4GB in the field.

See [MySQL data type storage requirement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: I changed the field to TEXT with utf8_unicode_ci. Fits all the text but still getting Â Â characters?

Answer (score 1):

Set the connection charset.

Put after making the connection:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```